# Dataframes in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, if-statement

This is my first time posting, so go easy on me.

I have got the data frame (as shown on the link, I don't have enough rep points to link an image yet). I am trying to run some course wise analysis. Issue is that I have got a few students who are doing dual degrees, and as such need to appear in calculations for both departments.

**Dataframe**

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to do that.

I am think I can write a stopgate statement where syntax checks if the Course2 column is empty or not before doing the analysis for each course. I cannot quite figure out how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add some data to copy and paste in R (fake or using `dput(your_data)` and post the output, your attempts and a precise desired output to have more chances to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which(is.na(df$Course2))` to check which row of Course2 is empty. (Suppose your dataframe name as `df`)